# Doctrine Repository getEntityManager() does returns empty

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an application I am coding with Symfony2.  I have created an Account entity and used the annotation to create a repository called AccountRepository  Inside the AccountRepository object I have created a function to run some business logic that goes out to an outside vendor and creates a user at their site, and returns the information back to us so I can associate their user with our Account Entity.  Part of creating that user includes sending over credit card token.  They then return some limited credit card data I want to store and associate with our account so I have an entity AccountCard after creating the object and inserting the appropriate data, I am unable to request the entity manager from the repository and persist the AccountCard doing a print_r on the $em variable shows nothing, yet everything I've read tells me I should be able to do this.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

namespace Openbridge\CommonBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

use Openbridge\CommonBundle\Entity\Account as Account;
use Openbridge\CommonBundle\Entity\AccountCard as AccountCard;
use Openbridge\CommonBundle\Entity\AccountAddress as AccountAddress;

/**
 * AccountRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class AccountRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    function createVendorUser(Account $account, $userData = array())
    {
        // Request new user from vendor code here. (this works)

        $ac = new AccountCard();
        // setters for $ac data here.

        // Get entity manager
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($ac);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your full entityRepository code in a gist? And what about the typehint `array()`. I have never seen that before, shouldn't that be `array $userData = array()`?

Comment: i modified here, there really isn't a lot of code other than what I already posted just the default Repository stuff Symfony makes from the Entity annotations and the inclusion of the other Entities we are using, and the vendor code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remove the constructor, because [EntityRepository](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L67) uses that to bind the dependencies to the class.

Comment: I really hate it when I make noob mistakes.  Thank you for pointing that out.